# Rewrite CSS Nesting as SASS

Tags: css, sass, postcss

So I came across this CSS snippet [here](https://web.dev/building-a-theme-switch-component/#sun-and-moon-svg-styles)

```css
.sun-and-moon {
  & > :is(.moon, .sun, .sun-beams) {
    transform-origin: center center;
  }

  & > :is(.moon, .sun) {
    fill: var(--icon-fill);

    @nest .theme-toggle:is(:hover, :focus-visible) > & {
      fill: var(--icon-fill-hover);
    }
  }

  & > .sun-beams {
    stroke: var(--icon-fill);
    stroke-width: 2px;

    @nest .theme-toggle:is(:hover, :focus-visible) & {
      stroke: var(--icon-fill-hover);
    }
  }
}
```

The author claims

> The CSS @nest feature, used with PostCSS Nesting, allows authoring new styles without leaving a selectors context. The above nested selector creates .theme-toggle > svg because the & character is dynamically represented as .theme-toggle.

> @nest is used again, this time to make a new selector that targets a parent button being hovered or focused. @nest .theme-toggle:is(:hover, :focus-visible) & in this usage is the same as @nest .theme-toggle:is(:hover, :focus-visible) .sun-and-moon > .sun-beams.

From what I understand the author basically manages to use a not yet available feature [CSS Nesting](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting/) using [postcss-plugins](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/tree/main/plugins/postcss-nesting)

I don't want to use PostCSS plugins. So the `@nest` does not work for me. How would I rewrite this particular CSS snippet with just SASS?

Comment: It is just syntactic sugar. Did you take a look at how it's implemented?  [Here](https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-nesting/#at-nest)

Answer (score 0):

I know I am not doing the work for you but I hope this helps:

[@nest Spec](https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-nesting/#at-nest)

```css
.foo {
  color: red;
  @nest & > .bar {
    color: blue;
  }
}

/* equivalent to
   .foo { color: red; }
   .foo > .bar { color: blue; }
*/
```